# Redundant argument in printf at /usr/bin/pt-table-checksum

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pt-table-checksum

While **pt-table-checksum** seems to work well for most tables, a few of the big ones get this:

> Error checksumming table mydb.mytable: Redundant argument in printf
>   at /usr/bin/pt-table-checksum line 8106.

Versions:

> pt-table-checksum 2.2.11

Servers (MariaDB acting as both slave to MySQL and master to another MariaDB, happens in both cases):

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.36, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine
>   wrapper mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.24-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)
>   using readline 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking at a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-toolkit/+bug/1480719)? Try updating.

Comment: Maybe so. While Percona toolkit is at v3.0.4 it seems that gentoo is far behind having * dev-db/percona-toolkit
     Available versions:  2.2.11 ~2.2.17 ~2.2.19 ~2.2.20
     Homepage:            https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-tools/percona-toolkit
     Description:         Advanced command-line tools to perform a variety of MySQL and system tasks

Comment: What a mess. `Error checksumming table myDb.myTable: Redundant argument in printf at /usr/bin/pt-table-checksum line 8183` Perl, Maatkit, Percona.. OMG FFS.